# Read only arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I want to create a read only array in my c# code

```
 private readonly string[] students = new string[] { "Alice", "John" };
```

Compiler does not complain about it but I read on the following link that array fields should not be read only. what is the best way of creating a read only array?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2105?view=vs-2019

How can I make a read only array? I just need a static array to check against other values

Comment: If the field is private, why are you concerned with making it read only?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class

Comment: An array is readonly in the sense that you can't change the pointer to another array. Since net core 2.1, you could use a `ReadOnlySpan`.